# Why is my theme table row array not being displayed?

Tags: 7, theming

I have the below code and I know both the $headers and the $html have values stored in them as i can echo them out.
I can also set the *'header' =>* in the theme function to be either $header or $html and it will display the data.

However when I add in *'rows' =>*, no data is displayed.

Can anyone see why?

```
function emnies_ad_hoc_query_exporter_get_html_formatted_ad_hoc_query_responses($obj_response) {
  $str_current_country = '';

  foreach ($obj_response as $response) {
    if ($str_current_country != $response->country) {
      $str_current_country = $response->country;
      $html = emnies_ad_hoc_query_exporter_get_country_row($str_current_country, $obj_response);
    }
  }
  $header = array('Country', 'Wider Dissemination', 'Responses'); 
  $output = theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header, 
    'rows' => $html
  ));
  return $output;
}



function emnies_ad_hoc_query_exporter_get_country_row($str_current_country, $obj_response) {
  $rows = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($obj_response as $response) {
    if ($str_current_country == $response->country) {
      if ($i == 0) {
        $rows[] = $str_current_country;
        $rows[] = $response->wider_dissemination;
      }
      $i = $i + 1;
      $rows[] = $response->response;
    }
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

Comment: What does `$response->response` return?  Also what exactly are you trying to do with your function?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at it this way.  From looking at your $header, you are looking for 3 columns?

```
foreach ($obj_response as $response) {
if ($str_current_country == $response->country) {
  $rows[] = array($str_current_country, $response->wider_dissemination, $response->response);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
// Test Output
$header = array(t('Country'), t('Wider Dissemination'), t('Responses'));
$rows = array();
$rows[] = array('US', 'Extremely Wide', 'Response');
print theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
```

The test works for me.  Maybe something in your response value is messing with it?

Comment: Thanks @iLLin,
However even if I use  
    '$header = array('Country', 'Wider Dissemination'); 
     $html = array(' Answer 1', 'Answer 2'); 
     $output = theme('table', array('rows' => $header,'rows' => $html)); 
     return $output;'

It still doesn't work. I just get the error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in include() (line 114 of sites/all/themes/ec_resp/templates/global/table.tpl.php)"

Comment: Edited the response.

Comment: Also, from your comment, you have rows listed twice in your theme('table').